# How to use a variable for the criteria argument in a Dcount

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use a Dcount to determine if a particular item is in a table. I think my issue is I am using a variable for the criteria part of the argument but I'm not sure. I don't get an error, the code to just leaves the loop completely, which I don't want. Is my issue the criteria part of the argument and if so, how do I fix it.

```
Set Events = Worksheets("Tables").ListObjects("Events")
Dim exist As Double
Dim Eventrow as integer
Dim eventSID as String
Dim Event2025 as String
   exist = 0


With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("2025")
    ScheRow = Worksheets("2025").Cells(Rows.Count, "a").End(xlUp).Row
    EventRow = 2
    EventSID = Worksheets("2025").Cells(EventRow, "a")


    Do While EventRow <= ScheRow
        Event2025 = Worksheets("2025").Cells(EventRow, "j")
        exist = Application.WorksheetFunction.DCount(Events.Range, 1, & Event2025)
```

Comment: Can you post your completed code?

Comment: It's a lot of code. The DCount was just added today. Is there some other part of the code that's needed for more information?